# Least period of sum of simple sines and cosines.

Tags: trigonometric-series

Given a finite summation of sines and cosines of the form 
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \left(A_i\sin(\omega_ix)\right)+\sum_{j=1}^p \left(B_j\cos(\sigma_jx)\right)$$
where $A_i,\omega_i\in\mathbb{Z}$ $\forall i\in[1,n]\cap\mathbb{N}$ and $B_j,\sigma_j\in\mathbb{Z}$ $\forall j\in[1,p]\cap\mathbb{N}$. How do we prove that the *least* period of the summation is the LCM of the periods of the constituent sines and cosines?

The challenge I am having is in proving that the LCM of individual periods is in fact the smallest period of the resulting periodic summation.

Comment: What are the "$\ldots$"? The first two terms you write has a sine and then a cosine; what comes next?

Comment: It's not a true statement (at least without some restrictions on the parameters). The least period of $\sin x + \cos 99 x + (-1)\cos 99x$ is not $99$, but $1$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: The dots mean that there are finitely more terms, each either a sine or a cosine, with the coefficients of $x$ as described.

Comment: @GregMartin: Actually it is $2\pi$. And that _is_, in that particular case, the least common multiple of the periods of the three terms, which are $2\pi$, $\frac{2\pi}{99}$, and $\frac{2\pi}{99}$.

Comment: The periods are of the form $\frac{2\pi}{\omega_i}$ or $\frac{2\pi}{\sigma_j}$. Let $T$ be the LCM of these periods and $f(x)$ your function. It's straightforward to prove that $f(x+T)=f(x)$.

Comment: @whatever: But the question asks for a proof of the fact that this is the 'least' period of the summation.

Comment: Prove that $f\left(x+\frac{T}{n}\right)\not=f(x)$ for any natural number $n>1$. I'm too lasy to write a proof now.

Comment: @whatever: Why does n have to be a natural number only?

Comment: Fair enough, I should have written $\sin 2\pi x + \cos \frac{2\pi}{99} x + (-1) \cos \frac{2\pi}{99} x$; the LCM of the periods is $99$ but the least period is $1$. My point is that some extra assumptions are needed to make the statement true, so trying to prove it as is isn't going to work.